# lwjgl's glfw.dll keeps crashing my JVM

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, jvm, lwjgl

Iv'e gotten the library imported to the work space along with the natives working, but when ever I run the test code from the website which can be found [here](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide).
I keep getting this fatal error and the JVM crashes.

[Here is the crash log](http://pastebin.com/EiCY3yMZ)

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why it's happening? I've tried updating JRE and JDK to the latest version, updating graphics drivers, re-downloading the library, trying older glfw.dll from older builds of LWJGL, Adjusting the JVM's memory arguments, and just creating a whole new work-space and trying again.
Is this a known bug with LWJGL?

System Specs from crash log:

> OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 10586 (10.0.10586.0)
>
> CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 60 stepping 3, >cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, >avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2
>
> Memory: 4k page, physical 16702524k(14116860k free), swap 19192892k(15542816k >free)
>
> vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14) for windows-amd64 JRE >(1.8.0_102-b14), built on Jun 22 2016 13:15:21 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

Comment: The access violation seems to be caused by a segmentation fault. i.e. the program tries to access memory that is out of bounds. It could be caused by the input you're feeding into the native code (or a bug therein).

Comment: I met that once. I used JDK6 to avoid this. But I think that is something wrong with the dll.